# Magento SOAP version 2 salesOrderCreditmemoAddComment and salesOrderInvoiceAddComment errors

Tags: magento, soap

I'm using the magento soap v2 api. I make a lot of salesOrderCreditmemoAddComment and salesOrderInvoiceAddComment. After a while, they stop working, and I get the following error:

> Cannot override final method Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::clearInstance()

Other api requests like catalogInventoryStockItemMultiUpdate, login, and endsession work fine. After I restart apache the addcomment requests start working again. I've worked around it by writing the comments directly into MYSQL, but does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I have found this which is helpful: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/378965/

I came across this problem once before after we had an outage, in our case, the Apache restart cleared it up, but i would look at that link: there's some interesting APC config changes that may (or may not) prevent it from re-occurring.